# Helping to get unanswered questions answered: What are the communities where we can notify people of our questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, sponsorship-and-advertising

I have been notifying these groups about unanswered questions on specific topics:

- LAMMPS: https://www.facebook.com/groups/lammps
- Quantum ESPRESSO: https://www.facebook.com/groups/Quantum.Espresso
- VASP: https://www.facebook.com/groups/Vasp.Code
- ABINIT: https://www.facebook.com/groups/AbinitCode
- CASTEP: https://www.facebook.com/groups/142037023098692
- Wien2k: https://www.facebook.com/groups/wien2k.Algeria/ https://www.facebook.com/groups/434787909952863/

However I came across this unanswered CP2K question: [Reading in E-field with CP2K](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3660/5)
and couldn't find an analogous place to post it, other than perhaps CP2K's own forum or mailing list, which I've never used, so I'm not comfortable enough with the culture of what might be appropriate to post there.

Where else can we post unanswered questions apart from the places already mentioned before (Psi-K forum, CCL, Molecular Dynamics News, and the above groups)?

Comment: I just posted [this question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11376/5) to four different docking groups.